# NgRx Effect results in infinite http loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx-effects

I have the following effect:

```
  initCompaniesAndSetCompanyEffect$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(
    (): Observable<Action> =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<changeCompanyActions.InitCompaniesAction>(changeCompanyActions.SelectedCompanyActionTypes.INIT_COMPANY),
        mergeMap(() =>
          this.companyService
            .getCompanies()
            .pipe(
              mergeMap((companies) => [new changeCompanyActions.LoadCompaniesAction(companies), new changeCompanyActions.InitSetCompanyAction(companies[0])])
            )
        )
      )
  );
```

And my actions:

```
export class InitCompaniesAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SelectedCompanyActionTypes.INIT_COMPANY;
}
export class LoadCompaniesAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SelectedCompanyActionTypes.LOAD_COMPANIES;
  constructor(public payload: Company[]) {}
}

export class InitSetCompanyAction implements Action {
  readonly type = SelectedCompanyActionTypes.INIT_COMPANY;
  constructor(public payload: Company) {}
}
```

and finally when dispatching onInit in my component:

```
  companies$: Observable<Company[]>;
  selectedCompany$: Observable<Company>;

  constructor(private store: Store<CompanyStoreState.SelectedCompanyState>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.companies$ = this.store.select(CompanyStoreSelectors.selectCompaniesList);
    this.selectedCompany$ = this.store.select(CompanyStoreSelectors.selectSelectedCompany);
    this.store.dispatch(new CompanyStoreActions.InitCompaniesAction());
  }
```

But this results in infinite http calls being made by the service and when looking around I don't see what it is that I'm doing different from solutions that I've found.
Anybody who could help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `InitSetCompanyAction` and `InitCompaniesAction` have the same type `SelectedCompanyActionTypes.INIT_COMPANY`

so when the effect fires, it loops back because the action you dispatch has the same type, so ofType picks that one up.

Comment: Omg, thank you! This can be removed/archived or whatever, any moderator I can tag to do that or can I do it myself?

Comment: @sincis you can just accept the answer, not neccessary to archive it...it can always be that someone does a similar error and googles it, so they will land here :)